# Open page as pdf with DOMPDF

Tags: html, css, dompdf

I am currently working on a semi dynamic page where I use some GET functionality to personalize it. I also echo the date a couple of places. At the bottom of this page, I would like to have a button that gives the visitor the option to download/open this page as PDF. Without the header. I have integrated DOMPDF, but I simply cant get it to work properly and need some help. I have tried a couple of things found here on Stackoverflow, with no success.

In basic, I need the whole page printed in the PDF, but it should not open when page is loaded. But triggered by the button. And then without the header (one spesific div). Is this possible?

```
<?php
    require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

    $html =
        '<html><body>'.
        '<p>This is a test for '.
        '<?php echo htmlentities(substr(urldecode($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]), 1)); ?> </p>'.
        '<p>Thank you for reading.</p>'.
        '</body></html>';

    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream("the_inquiry.pdf");
    return true;
    ?>
<html>
<body>
<div class="shouldnotPrintToPDF">
Content.
</div>
<div class="shouldPrintToPDF">
Sensitive content.
<a href="the_inquiry.pdf">Open or save as PDF</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is basically our one page presentation. And contains a lot of text, so I will not present all of that here. But in this way, I have to write the page twice, in $html = as well as inside the actual  tag. And the PDF save/open option pops up right from the start, which it should not. I also wish to append the echo htmlentities part to the actual pdf-name.. is this possible? The PDF opens and contains what put into the $html = just fine. But not triggered by the link.

Update:
When i do exactly what you perform here, I get an error "The requested URL /inquiry.php&pdf=1 was not found on this server." I have the page I am trying to print in pdf on root level, but the DOMPDF is in /dompdf.. I dont know if that has anything to do with it?

Update:
When i edited the link, i get all this information up in a new page, like below.

```
    [_parse_properties(margin:=1.2cm)(empty)_parse_properties]
[_parse_sections[section[_parse_properties(display:=-dompdf-page)
(counter-reset:=page)(empty)_parse_properties]#html#section]
[section[_parse_properties(empty)_parse_properties]#empty#section]
_parse_sections][_parse_sections[section[_parse_properties(display:=block)
(empty)_parse_properties]#div##map##dt##isindex#section]
[section[_parse_properties(empty)_parse_properties]#empty#section]
_parse_sections][_parse_sections[section[_parse_properties(page-break
-before:=avoid)(display:=block)(counter-increment:=page)
(empty)_parse_properties]#body#section]
[section[_parse_properties(empty)_parse_properties]#empty#section]_parse_sections]
[_parse_sections[section[_parse_properties(display:=block)(margin:=1em 
0)(empty)_parse_properties]#p##dl##multicol#section]
[section[_parse_properties(empty)_parse_properties]#empty#section]_parse_sections]
[_parse_sections[section[_parse_properties(display:=block)(margin-left:=40px)
(empty)_parse_properties]#dd#section]
[section[_parse_properties(empty)_parse_properties]#empty#section]_parse_sections]
[_parse_sections[section[_parse_properties(display:=block)(margin:=1em 
40px)(empty)_parse_properties]#blockquote#section]
[section[_parse_properties(empty)_parse_properties]#empty#section]_parse_sections]
[_parse_sections[section[_parse_properties(display:=block)(font-style:=italic)
(empty)_parse_properties]#address#section]
[section[_parse_properties(empty)_parse_properties]#empty#section]_parse_sections]
[_parse_sections[section[_parse_properties(display:=block)(text-align:=center)
(empty)_parse_properties]#center#section]
```

Do you have any idea what it might be caused by?

Breakthrough:

When I activated DOMPDF_DPI it actually opens as PDF, but now all of the text comes on first line of the second page of the PDF. Like, all the text comes out on top of each other. Also, when it opens the PDF, the ?&pdf=1 are included in the htmlentities query string, which looks very messy since it is supposed to be a personalized page as well as the PDF.

Comment: Show your code. What exactly did you try?

Comment: Added some info just now, can not paste entire page since it holds some what sensitive information.

Answer (score 1):

You can set dompdf to parse CSS @media queries for standard media types (screen, print, voice, etc.). By default dompdf parses the "screen" media type styles, but you can change this in the configuration file. See the [DOMPDF_DEFAULT_MEDIA_TYPE](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/blob/master/dompdf_config.inc.php#L182) configuration setting. Then you just need to pass the original URL querystring with an appended variable telling the page to render to PDF. If your original URL is something like `the_inquiry.php?name=Joe` then your PDF URL could be `the_inquiry.php?name=Joe&pdf=1`.

Your code would then look similar to the following:

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    @media print {
      .shouldnotPrintToPDF, .pdflink { display: none; }
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="shouldnotPrintToPDF">
    Content.
  </div>
  <div class="shouldPrintToPDF">
    Sensitive content.
    <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] , '?' , http_build_query( $_GET ); ?>&amp;pdf=1" class="pdflink">Open or save as PDF</a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
if ( isset( $_GET['pdf'] ) ) {
  require_once 'dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php';
  $html = ob_get_clean();
  $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
  $dompdf->load_html($html);
  $dompdf->render();
  $dompdf->stream("the_inquiry.pdf");
}
?>
```

Comment: When i do exactly what you perform here, i get an error "The requested URL /inquiry.php&pdf=1 was not found on this server." I have the page I am trying to print in pdf on root level, but the DOMPDF is in /dompdf.. I dont know if that has anything to do with it?

Comment: @John-EilifEliassen ah, sorry. I forgot the "?" in the URL, it should come out `inquiry.php?&pdf=1`. I updated the code sample.

Comment: would you look at my update and let me know what im doing wrong?

Comment: @John-EilifEliassen do you have $_dompdf_debug set to true? If so, make sure to disable all the debugging options.

Comment: Hi @BrianS, what debug? I find (DEBUG_LAYOUT, DEBUGCSS, DEBUGKEEPTEMP, DEBUGPNG) in dompdf_config.custom.inc.php. Some of them are true, some of them are false. In dompdf_config.inc.php on line 357 i have this: global $_dompdf_debug;$_dompdf_debug = false; So i guess i have debug set to false.

Comment: If you could access my page you would probably see what the issue is instantly, but I am still encountering the issue with debugged pdf (i guess). Is there any way I can send  you the information? It is quite sensitive information so I wont share it here.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the debug messages should be going into the log file, but something else might be going on as well. At any rate, make sure all the debug options are disabled (set to false).

Comment: They are all disabled now (false), but it still shows up on one singular line. Some text on first line of first pdf-page, and the rest apparently on first line of second pdf-page.

Comment: Let me think on it some more. If you want to send me some files you can do so here: http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/upload/. Password is `ag$%#QYUynser` (one-time use only, so create a zip of all relevant files).

Comment: I just sent you a zip of the root/dompdf folder. But I forgot to place some information on whom it belonged to in the zip :) So the issue.zip archive is from me.

Comment: If you have the chance to check the files, could you please give me feedback on my issue.rar ? :)